# Is it really bad practice to declare variables along with types in structured data types?

Tags: c++

My C++ textbook mentioned that it's generally bad practice to simultaneously declare variables with type declarations like the following:

> ```
> struct fullName
> {
>     string firstName;
>     string middleName;
>     string lastName;
> } examplePerson1, examplePerson2;
> ```

To me, this seems more reasonable given its conciseness and the alternative method, but I'm also still learning so I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could please elaborate as the textbook didn't.

Comment: Use the button { } for code blocks instead of ” on SO editor toolbar.

Comment: You'll end up with global variables, and that's definitely bad practice.

Comment: You cannot separate declaration (e.g. move the struct to its own header file) from use in this case.  Also your textbook is using `using namspace std;` (which is not a good practice in big projects). Also note writing the least amount of code lines is not a goal in itself. Try to limit the number of things you do in one line or in this case when you have two different responsibilities (declaring a type, and making an instance of that type).

Comment: It breaks at least one cppcoreguideline [**ES.10: Declare one name (only) per declaration**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not true if this is in the class scope.

Comment: @Chris Don know if this is opinionated, this has a specific readability downside. I feel like we could actually answer this question.

Comment: One person's "conciseness" is another person's "all in one big pile". Some of us think that "doing one thing at a time" is the way the achive clarity.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The code can also be part of a class definition or local to a function. In such cases it will not end in global vars. But yes, also in that cases it ends up in default initialized variables which is from my point of view often bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If your textbook gave zero rationale, it's not a very good textbook, and I wouldn't recommend taking what it says at face value. I for one don't see why this would be bad practice.

Doing this can (subjectivity warning) actually be used as a slightly-useful hint that the type might only be used by those variables / data members (Emphasis on "hint", since the struct/class *can* still be used to declare other variables of its type).

Note that if you declare *multiple* variables of that type like this, it does violate a C++ Core Guideline: [ES.10: Declare one name (only) per declaration](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration), but the rationale for that guideline is:

> Reason One declaration per line increases readability and avoids mistakes related to the C/C++ grammar. It also leaves room for a more descriptive end-of-line comment.
>
> Example, bad
>
> ```
> char *p, c, a[7], *pp[7], **aa[10];   // yuck!
> ```

I'd say the point on readability is debatable in this context, the point on mistakes with the C++ grammar doesn't always apply (and you can be careful), and the point on end of line comments may apply, but only if you really want to write comment descriptions for each variable of that type. Also consider that some of the same authors of the C++ Core Guidelines wrote the caveats about coding standards in https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards.